# Plotting Vectors using XY coords in Matlab from origin

Tags: matlab

I am new to Matlab and I'm having immense trouble using the plotting function. I have read the help and doc files but I'm no closer to finding the solution for what is a very basic task.

I have a function which produces X,Y coordinates for the end point of a vector originating from the origin. Valid values would be things like:

```
a = [0;1];
b = [0.5;0.8];
c = [1;3]
```

I have to plot these but I am lost on what is going on. It seems that every time I try to plot one these it uses one of the values within the matrix and it's index within the matrix as the other value. I have tried to offset this by transposing and concatenating with an origin matrix ( `origin = [0;0]` ) but I still end up with the the wrong results.

Examples of things I've tried are:

```
plot(b) - produces line from 1,0.5 to 2,0.8
plot(origin,b) - produces vertical line from 0,0 to 0,0.8
plot(transpose(origin),transpose(b)) - produces line from 2,0 to 3,0.5 then 4,0.8
plot([transpose(origin);transpose(b)]) - produces two lines from the origin, 1 to 2,0.5 and the other to 2,0.8.
```

(All above numbers are in x,y format)

I'm now lost and playing around in the command window trying everything to figure it out but am going crazy.

How do I plot a value like b = [0.5;0.8] so the vector originates at the origin and finishes at x = 0.5 and y = 0.8 on the plot?

Thanks.

Comment: plot([0,b(1)],[0,b(2)]);

Comment: Is the first line in the documentation!!! `plot(X,Y)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To plot a line from `(x0,y0)` to `(x,y)` the call is

`plot([x0,x],[y0,y])`;

So the answer is `plot([0,b(1)],[0,b(2)]);`